# In IPython every shell command is run by prefixing it with "!" but few commands run without that, What is the reason behind it?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

In case of "ls" command it runs with and without the prefix "!". In case of "cat fileName" it's the same, but when you consider "wc -l fileName" it works only with "!" prefix.

When you combine cat and wc command "cat fileName | wc -l" executed successfully without "!" prefix.

I don't understand the logic behind this prefix "!" in ipython.

Thank you in advance
(I am new to python programming, if it sounds silly question please forgive me.)

Answer (score 0):

IPython tries to make interactive programming as comfortable as possible. Some shell builtins like ls, cd or cat are basic commands to navigate in unix shells. IPython, as a "Python Shell" provides the same functionally for convenience. Along with features like colored output, etc.

The `!command` is for executing arbitrary shell code and is much more powerful. It can be used to run any command you can type in a normal shell and can also catch its output.

Compare `ls` with `!ls`. The former will print the content in your current directory with nice coloring. The latter will print the same list, but just plain text.

But note that you can do really cool things with `!command`:

```
files = !ls
for f in files:
    print("I like this file:", f)
```

Which reads the output of `ls` into a python array `files` which you can use in your code just like any other array.

To sum up: if you just want to navigate, you usually use the standard commands, if available. If you need to capture the output or run programs you have to use the `!command` syntax.